# Can a format value "divide" a number in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, number-formatting

One of the columns of my table has values that can typically range from 3500 to 8 million. Is it possible to specify a format that can divide the number when formatting?

For example, I have the following values:

```
3500
81000
1678500
```

Ideally I would like a format value (coming from another config table) that would format the numbers in "thousands" with 1 decimal place:

```
3.5
81.0
1678.5
```

But this format value could also be different for other cases, so they could be formatted in millions with two decimal places:

```
0.00
0.08
1.68
```

Is this possible, or do I need to divide the numbers myself before applying the formatting?

Comment: "Formating" is not a database concern, leave it to the presentation layer and let the DB care about storage. Numbers, all by themselves, have no inherent format at all.

Comment: Hopefully you're going to put an exponent on it, otherwise it kinda ruins your data?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, I hopefully wanted a formatting like "[k]0.00 KB", where the "[k]" was the divisor, but it was just wishful thinking. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible, or do I need to divide the numbers myself before applying the formatting?

You need to do the division. You can use CASE WHEN, by the way, if you aren't having numeric values to track what to divide by:

```
SELECT tablevalue / CASE divby WHEN 'thousand' THEN 1000 WHEN 'million' THEN 1000000 ELSE 1 END
```

I presume you'll have some column in your "format" table that also specifies what to divide by..

---

So you don't want to add a column.. you can store the info in the existing column.. you just have to work more to get it out:

```
SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(
    somenumber / CASE RIGHT(format, 1) WHEN 'k' THEN 1000 WHEN 'M' THEN 1000000 END,
    LEFT(format, -1)
  )
```

So now you can make your format like `99D99k` and the k will cause a divide by 1000 and the result is formatted to 99.99, so if you have `1234`, format `9.99k` you'll get `'1.23'`out of it.

If you want the `[k]` at the start it's just some jiggling of the LEFT and RIGHT functions..

```
  TO_CHAR(
    somenumber / CASE LEFT(format, 3) WHEN '[k]' THEN 1000 WHEN '[M]' THEN 1000000 END,
    RIGHT(format, -3)
  )
```

Comment: I see. I was trying to avoid an extra column for the "divisor". I guess I have no option. Thanks.